# Синхронизация остатков МойСклад

Tags: moysklad-json-api

требуется синхронизация остатков товаров и их модификаций в магазине. Для этого использую JSON API. Изначально использовал сущность ассортимент ([https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/doc/index.html#ассортимент](https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/doc/index.html#%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82))

Но потом выяснил, что каждый раз необходимо загружать и перепроверять остатки ВСЕХ товаров и их модификаций, да еще и в двух складах, что выполняется очень долго и создает ненужную нагрузку на сервер.

Возник вопрос: зачем по 2 раза сравнивать остатки по 3,6к товаров и модификаций (для каждого склада - отдельно), если с последней проверки остатки изменились только у двух-трех позиций?

В сущности Ассортимент имеется поле для фильтрации updated, но по нему фильтруется не последняя дата изменения остатков, а последняя дата изменения самой сущности товара или модификации.

Имеется ли возможность через API запрашивать только те остатки, которые изменились за последние 20-30 минут, а не весь ассортимент? (Отчет stockbyStore даст тоже абсолютно все остатки).
Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: По правилам форума в тексте может быть только один вопрос :)  Гляньте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Мне кажется, что Вы быстрее получите ответ, если конкретизируете вопрос и еще не много поработаете над текстом вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

В ближайшее время будет релиз версии апи 1.2 и в ней будет вебхук на остатки.